# Ever see "There was a prob saving this record. did not find required record type" but it made no sense?

Tags: save, ckrecord

Ever see "There was a problem saving this record. did not find required record type" but it made no sense?

Answer (score 1):

Sharing from my experience.
in my case,
I **deleted** RecordType with record that had recordname **XXXX**

Then I created **new** RecordType and tried to add new record with the **same** recordName **XXXX**
and cloudKit gave me the error :
"There was a prob saving this record. did not find required record type” but it made no sense?"

changing the recordname to something else, and  I could save the new record.

This mean that cloudKit still remember the recordName belong to the old recordType that was deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an iOS bug. I discovered that setting a CKRecord with a record name of "ID-"+the user cloud id causes this failure to save a record. If "ID-" is changed to just "ID" or if the "_" is removed from the user cloud id, everything works fine. Very strange. It happens in code and in the CloudKit Dashboard.